# while count not working with inputs

Tags: python

I need to create a program that reads multiple inputs and when 0 is pressed it shows how many numbers between 100 and 200 were typed. Here's my code:

```
def counting():
    total = 0
    entry = int(input("Type a number: "))
    while entry != 0:
        entry = int(input("Type a number: "))
        if 100 < entry < 200:
            total += 1

    print(total)
```

It works fine except when the first number typed is between 100 and 200. If i type '123', '150', and '0', I'll get 1 (the first input is not counted). Any tips to fix this?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

note the double `input` statement which eats your first value (and is duplicated code which also should be avoided), that you could avoid like this:

```
while True:
    entry = int(input("Type a number: "))
    if 100 < entry < 200:
        total += 1
    if entry == 0:
       break
```

Using an infinite loop which breaks manually when the value is 0, you test the value every time and you avoid the copy of the `input` statement.

(python doesn't have a `do` / `while` type statement, so that's the closer you can get to have a statement executed at least once)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving input for `entry` after `if` condition, otherwise first time it is asked is ignored:

```
def counting():
    total = 0
    entry = int(input("Type a number: "))
    while entry != 0:
        if 100 < entry < 200:
            total += 1
        entry = int(input("Type a number: ")) # moved

    print(total)
```